# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSManagedObjectContext save method inside NSOperation and ARC, why?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, exc-bad-access, automatic-ref-counting

I have found some problems when saving NSManagedObjectContext inside NSOperation with turned on ARC. Without ARC everything was fine before. It is always gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS during saving. The code looks like this:

```
//on the main thread
-(void)someFunc
{
    array = ... //fetching an array of entities from a core data
    for(SomeEntity * obj in array)
    {
         NSSomeOperation * op = [[NSSomeOperation alloc] initWithValue:[obj someField]];
         //start an operation
    }
}

//NSSomeOperation implementation
//...
- (void)main {
    //some code
    NSError * error = nil;
    [mainContext lock];
    if (![mainContext save:&error]) {    //<--- HERE EXC_BAD_ACCESS
       //process error
    }      
    [mainContext unlock];
    //some code
}
//...
```

Using of [mainContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES] and objectWithID don't resolve this issue.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13)

```
-[__NSCFType contextDidSave:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc5c505d940

An observer of NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification illegally threw an exception.

Objects saved = {
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n    <SomeEntity: 0x7fc5c55b6220> (entity: SomeEntity; id: 0x7fc5c5052b20 ... )}"; } 
and exception = -[__NSCFType contextDidSave:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc5c505d940 with userInfo = (null)
```

I use a separate managed object context and fetch my managed objects inside this NSOperation.

Maybe it is something related to Core Data bugs or ARC? Maybe ARC cleans some of objects, that must be saved? 
Because, without ARC everything was fine, all worked. When I turned on ARC - EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Does anyone know why it occurs?

Comment: No, Jim. This is inside NSOperation, on the another thread.

Comment: Okay, the reason I ask is because you can add an NSOperation to the main queue (using NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:...]. If this is on a secondary thread or queue, are you following the Apple documentation to use a separate managed object context, and merge your changes back into the context in the main queue?

Comment: NSOperationQueue on main thread, yes. Yes, I'm creating second NSManagedObjectContext inside NSOperation, but in init method. And merge changes with performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) on main NSManagedObjectContext(which created on main thread). Maybe I need to create NSManagedObjectContext object (second) inside "main" method of the NSOperation?

Comment: It looks like all of that is right, if it's on the main thread. YOu shouldn't need performSelectorOnMainThread, if you are already on the main thread, but that shouldn't matter. Also, it doesn't matter if you use init or main if it's on the main thread. (You should use the start method for work that has to be on a secondary thread, but that's irrelevant in the case you describe.)

Comment: If you can post your project, I'll take a look at it to see if I can suggest anything.

Comment: Thanks, John, but I can't post project.

Answer (score 27):

Maybe ARC deallocates some object that receives **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification** and this causes the exception?
I had something similar, and fixed it by making sure to **removeObserver:** before the object gets deallocated.

Note that the CoreData exception actually hides the notification center exception, so you don't get to see it.

Comment: Thanks Yonat! Yes, you are absolutely right. I've just tried to removeObserver: - and it doesn't help.

Comment: I called `removeObserver:` in `dealloc` of my singleton with shared context. Removing `dealloc` resolved problem, but where I should to `removeObserver`?

Comment: Also check if you haven't called addObserver more than once. Rule of thumb is to do it on viewDidLoad and call removeObserver on dealloc.