# The NSManagedObjectContext saves changes asynchronously or synchronously?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, synchronization, automatic-ref-counting

The NSManagedObjectContext saves changes asynchronously or synchronously?

If asynchronously, then how can I wait for saving changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Synchronously.**

You can put any code you want to run after saving just after the `save` call.

The methods `-(void)willSave` and `-(void)didSave` on `NSManagedObject` allow you to perform behaviour on your model class after/before save.

If you're on the Mac you can also watch for a notification called [NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-237802)

Comment: Thank you John, i've just maked a question because I thought if asynchronously, then it can partially explain my another question about NSManagedObjectContext [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419048/exc-bad-access-on-nsmanagedobjectcontext-save-method-inside-nsoperation-and-arc)